# How can javascript be executed in background without opening popup.html in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome that requires a Firebase database. It works fine, "popup.html" is currently open. But when it closes, my background.js stops working.

I need a solution that will allow background.js to work in the background, even when the popup.html is closed, or the browser is minimized.

Here is my background.js:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var clipText;

setInterval(function() {

document.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {

    clipText = event.clipboardData.getData('Text');

    if (clipText != null) {

        db.child('data').set(clipText);
    } else {

        console.log('Cliptext is null...');
    }
});

  document.execCommand('paste');
  }, 3000)
```

As you see, it uses "setInterval" function to do some actions in background every 3 seconds.

Comment: Is your background.js file in the manifest.json?

Comment: "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["<all_urls>"],"js": ["background.js"]}],

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you are declaring your `background.js` in the content script.

You need to declare it inside your `manifest.json` like this for example:

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "background.js"]
},
```

You can read about Chrome Extensions architecture [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).